# Update UI in app switcher

Tags: ios, ios7, multitasking

How can I update my app's UI when it is shows in the app switcher, specifically at that second.

I have watched the WWDC video "What's new with Multitasking" but their approaches were always updating the UI in response to new information or based on an amount of time that passed.

I redraw a part of my UI every second, and I would like the user to get the information they want without even having to open my app. I don't want to redraw my UI every second it is in the background, just once when the app is shown on the app switcher or when the app switcher loads.

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly answer your question - it's not at the instant that the user enters the task switcher - but why not use applicationWillEnterBackground to make changes to the UI so that when the user pulls it up later, it'll already be set?

Comment: My app redraws a part of its UI every single second, so that approach really won't help me.

Comment: You will not be able to achieve what you need. Not officially, not for app store, unless it's a location based app.

Even Apple's own software does not do that.

Comment: "updating the UI [...] based on an amount of time that passed"

It sounds like you could (very inefficiently) achieve what you want by continuously redrawing every second while in the background, but you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: My app would update every second, so I feel iOS would slaughter my app with a vengeance for stealing so much power.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean when the user is inside your app and double clicks, then you should update when your application resigns active. If you mean, when the application is in the background and the user passes by in the task switcher, the only way to do that is by implementing push functionality and updating your UI when a push is received. Updating specifically only when the user goes into the switcher is not currently possible. Look into the push backgrounding mode, it is the closest to what you need.

Even Apple's own software does not update its views in the background often. For example, the music app, the weather app, the compass app, etc.

**It is a monumental waste of system resources to often update UI in the background, and will give bad experience to your users. Your best bet is a design change.**

Comment: Extrapolated on my question - I mean the second one. Push notifications would be a terrible waste of system and server resources to push out updates every second, or even every minute.

Comment: Yes that is true. I am not sure what your software does, but you will not be able to achieve anything better. You could try background fetch mode, but that will not work for every second. It is a monumental waste of system resources to update UI in the background, and will give bad experience to your users

Comment: I have tried background fetch, but it really doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7.0 I don't know of any documented way to get notified when the app switcher is about to display your app in the carousel. It's possible there is a [notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver%3aselector%3aname%3aobject%3a) published that you could subscribe to - add a subscriber for all sources, no name filter, that just logs the details of each notification, then play around with the switcher and see if your app gets any notification. I doubt they are publishing this though; since it's a brand new task switcher, and background updates is a new API as well, Apple is probably not going to open any of the API for updating the app as a result of being displayed by the switcher until at least 7.1 (they have historically dog-fooded new APIS for at least one minor version, usually one major version).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:nil object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
 //Log the interesting bits of the notification.
}];
```

Don't leave this code in your release build, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the clever answer, but I couldn't find anything relevant.